# Trying to log in to gmail while using TestCafe

Tags: ssl, testing, automated-tests, gmail, testcafe

I am learning TestCafe and am trying to create an account on a website and then logging in to Gmail to find the activation link. When I try to do this I just get a browser isn't secure message when I get to the part to enter a password. How do I get Gmail to trust TestCafe?

Answer (score 4):

While you might succeed in doing so, this is not a good approach because:

- it's slow doing this via GUI
- it's britle because selectors will likely change, and you have no control over Google email selectors, so you won't even know if they change them

A better approach wuld be to use a service like [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com/) where you can create an account and receive emails that you can later query via an API. Instead of doing a whole e2e flow over GUI, you request an email on Mailosaur's API, and if such an email exists, you'll receive a response you can parse and check for various things.

I've done this in the past, you can see my post here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40427/automating-verification-of-sent-email-sms-messages/45721#45721 It's exactly Mailosaur and Testcafe (plus it requires [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) as a package), so it seems to be what you're looking for.

To add the same code here:

```js
import config from '../config';
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid';
import axios from 'axios';
import Newsletter from '../Objects/newsletter';

async function request (reqObject) {  
    try {
        return await axios(reqObject);            
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

function serverId () {
    return process.env.MAILOSAUR_SERVER_ID;
}

function mailosaurFullEmail (id) {
    return (id ? id : nanoid()) + '.' + serverId() 
        + '@' + config.mailosaurDomain;
}

fixture `Newsletter`    
    .page(baseUrl);

test             
    ('Sign Up For Newsletter', async t => {

        const id = (customAlphabet('1234567890', 10))();

        await t
            .typeText(Newsletter.newsEmailInput, mailosaurFullEmail(id))
            .click(Newsletter.consent)
            .click(Newsletter.sendButton);

        let res = await request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: config.mailosaurUrlEmail + serverId(),
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' 
                    + Buffer.from(process.env.MAILOSAUR_API_KEY)
                        .toString('base64'),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                sentTo: mailosaurFullEmail(id)
            }
        });       
        
        await t
            .expect(res.status).eql(200);
});
```

and it requires some config values:

```json
{
    "mailosaurUrlEmail": "https://mailosaur.com/api/messages/await?server=",
    "mailosaurDomain": "mailosaur.io"
}
```

This is definitely much better, but it still has some limitations:

- Mailosaur's API can still change, so it won't be exactly without any maintenance
- it assumes that an email is sent immediately after a user action (newsletter in my case), but that might be far from reality in many situations such as when emails are sent to a queue where it can easily take several minutes to send an email

---

If you absolutely have to do it via Gmail, you will still be better off looking at their [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) that should allow you to search and query email messages as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is [an issue related to the Google login](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2438). You can try turning on the ["Allow less secure apps"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) Google account setting to workaround this issue. Please note that this setting is available for the disabled [2-Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/).